# package android.view.ActionMode does not exist android.view.ActionMode.Callback

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am making android xamarin project using visual studo 2013 in c# and i get this error when i buid a solution

```
package android.view.ActionMode does not exist  android.view.ActionMode.Callback
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action Mode is supported by at least API 12 in my application was API 10